# Can Import A 3D Model into madmapper

Tags: 3d, projector

I'm looking for a way to projection map onto a low poly 3d model, I would like to use [mad mapper](http://www.madmapper.com/), but I can seem to figure out if there is a way to load the 3d model into madmapper rather than sit there an draw the surfaces in the program by hand.

How to load a 3d geometry into it?

Comment: Alternatively I'd suggest using blender with blam: https://vimeo.com/56955831

Comment: this looks very cool, the only thing is that all the blender stuff would need to be pre-rendered, I'm really looking to do something interactive and have the video feed be live

Comment: for interactivity you could use the game engine of blender, see: http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/3dcanvas_blender_plab/index.html